# How shall I resolve this "Memory Error" in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I am using numpy for making a zeroes matrix using np.zeros((x,y))

But my notebook says memory error on this.
**Note: my x is 92106 and y is 241071**.

I guess it's because of these large values that I'm getting an error. Is there any way I can resolve this error? Or basically handle this error?

Comment: What is your RAM and your numpy version?

Comment: @SaranrajNambusubramaniyan Using dual Boot system. RAM: 8GB and numpy version 1.13.3

Comment: You'll need at least 1299013 GB of RAM to create an array that big (assuming you're using a 64-bit datatype). If you need to work with that much data, NumPy alone is not the right choice - a distributed system would preferable...

Comment: Obviously you can't hold the entire array in memory but there are various alternatives that can work in different scenarios. So please provide some context - why do you need to create such a big array? How will you process it further?

Comment: I agree with @AlexRiley. I will update an alternative solution for you.

Comment: @kazemakase I actually was initially thinking of creating a pivot table, but that definitely wasn't possible. This is for a recommendation system algo i've been working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As updated by Alex in comment, your RAM doesn't have enough memory to handle such big array and Numpy is not the optimal choice. You can use sparse matrix to create such array. Here is one way to do that,

```
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix
import numpy as np
d = dia_matrix((92106 , 241071), dtype=np.int8).toarray()
print(d.shape)  #(92106, 241071) which is a numpy array.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That actually helped. Thank you!